# Failed to open existing projects due to I\O error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

While trying to open a project I observe the following error.

error  : An IO error occurred while scanning the disk for installed platforms.

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed and the same project was working earlier. I have installed Python 2.6, SCons, command line version of SVN for a different project and then onwards am seeing this failure.

Could you suggest the possible error here?